# Fragment Container in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-jetpack-compose

I want to develop a single Activity multi fragments Apps using **Jetpack Compose**. 
For recyclerView, we have Vertical and HorizontalScroller. But, for fragments what should I use.

```
fun loadFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
            val transaction:FragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            transaction.replace(R.id.f_container, fragment)
            transaction.addToBackStack(null)
            transaction.commit()
        }
```

In this case, I don't have R.id.f_container because I'm creating UI using only compose.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/f_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"`enter code here`
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="-56dp">
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Fragments need a `ViewGroup` container. That is unlikely to change. So, if you want to continue using fragments, you will need a `ViewGroup` in the appropriate place. Right now, with Compose/view interoperability very much a "work in progress", that probably means that your fragment will need to go into a traditional layout.

Comment: @Thaw De Zin if you have found a solution for your question please let me know

Comment: This might address your question https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/load-fragments-in-jetpack-compose-beyond-what-google-taught-356a7981268d?sk=43b363c34040c646454d1629ef5f504b

Comment: what about using `AndroidViewBinding` that loads a navhost fragment (with nav graph possibly), then with navigation component you basically can also navigate through fragments that renders compose in this scenario https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/migrate/interoperability-apis/views-in-compose#androidview_with_view_binding

Answer (score 13):

You can create your own @Composable FragmentContainer function

```kotlin
@Composable
fun FragmentContainer(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    fragmentManager: FragmentManager,
    commit: FragmentTransaction.(containerId: Int) -> Unit
) {
    val containerId by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(View.generateViewId()) }
    var initialized by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }
    AndroidView(
        modifier = modifier,
        factory = { context ->
            FragmentContainerView(context)
                .apply { id = containerId }
        },
        update = { view ->
            if (!initialized) {
                fragmentManager.commit { commit(view.id) }
                initialized = true
            } else {
                fragmentManager.onContainerAvailable(view)
            }
        }
    )
}

/** Access to package-private method in FragmentManager through reflection */
private fun FragmentManager.onContainerAvailable(view: FragmentContainerView) {
    val method = FragmentManager::class.java.getDeclaredMethod(
        "onContainerAvailable",
        FragmentContainerView::class.java
    )
    method.isAccessible = true
    method.invoke(this, view)
}
```

and then use it in activity

```kotlin
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
        FragmentContainer(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager,
            commit = { add(it, YourFragment()) }
        )
    }
}
```

or in fragment

```kotlin
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View = ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
    setContent {
        FragmentContainer(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            fragmentManager = parentFragmentManager,
            commit = { add(it, YourNestedFragment()) }
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: This requires Fragment KTX library, e.g. `implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.4.1"`

Comment: While the above works, there are some limitations, as stated in  https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/load-fragments-in-jetpack-compose-beyond-what-google-taught-356a7981268d?sk=43b363c34040c646454d1629ef5f504b

Answer (score 4):

I would not suggest you reuse an existing fragment, but instead, try to recycle its inner views to create a new composable.

Anyway if you want to have fun here is a possible solution:

```
AndroidView(
modifier = Modifier
    .fillMaxHeight()
    .fillMaxWidth(),
factory = { context ->
    FrameLayout(context).apply {
        FragmentBlankBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), this, true).root
    }
})
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score -2):

If you are creating a new app, you can skip using Fragments altogether and just use composable functions to represent your screens.

Comment: +1 - I don't understand the negative votes under that comment. Fragments are just containers, they can be replaced with any other containers. It may turn out that best practices will change in favor of what is stated in this comment.